# Drupal 7 File Field Library

Tags: drupal, upload, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm trying to add a field of 'file' type that includes not only an upload button, but also a 'browse' or 'library' button that would show a list of already uploaded files. This would prevent having to upload duplicates if they are reused across the site.

I've tried both iterations of the Media module, but they are incomplete as it seems.

Are there any module suggestions? Or am I missing a simple core option that allows this? I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using file field sources module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources

And it works well for me.

Comment: That is perfect! Works much better than the Media module. Thank you for your help.